# sql command not properly ended for select statement

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a pl/sql function and in that i have the following piece of code:

```
execute immediate 'select ' || schemaname || '.' || value1 || '_seq.nextval from dual into cnpParmId';
```

for this line, I am getting an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

In the above code I am getting the `value1` from the result of a select query. `schemaname` is the input of the function and `cnpParmId` is the return value of the function.

I tried different ways to solve this but I still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without showing us more of your procedure, but I think it's a fair guess that you didn't mean to concatenate `cnpParmId` in your dynamic SQL (how could the dynamic SQL possibly know how to interpret `cnpParmId`?). `cnpParmId` is probably defined somewhere in your procedure.

Instead, you probably meant to use the `into` clause of the [execute immediate](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) command:

```
execute immediate 'select ' || schemaname || '.' || value1 || '_seq.nextval from dual'
into cnpParmId;
```

Comment: this is how the function looks like:

Comment: sorry, I just realized I was saying `returning into`, when it should have simply been `into`. But the point is the same, the `into` clause should not be part of the dynamic SQL.

Comment: I tried it this way, but doent work: execute immediate 'select ' || schemaname || '.' || value1 || '_seq.nextval from dual' into cnpParmId;  Error:SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CNPPARMID": invalid identifier

Comment: Like I said in my post: *It's hard to say without showing us more of your procedure*. I assumed you must have had a `cnpParmId` variable somewhere in your procedure. But apparently you don't.  What is `cnpParmId`, then?